# Modelbinding database entities in ASPNET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, model-view-controller, modelbinders

I'm having trouble trying to think what the best way is to recreate a database object in a controller Action.

I want to make use of ModelBinders so in my action I have access to the object via a parameter, rather than having to repeat code to get an object from the database based on an identifier parameter. So I was thinking of having a ModelBinder that performs a call to the dataaccess layer to obtain the original object (or creates a new one if it doesn't exist in the database), then binds any properties to the database object to update it. However I've read that the ModelBinders shouldn't make database queries (first comment of this [article](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Model_Binders_in_ASPNET_MVC.aspx)).

If the ModelBinder shouldn't perform a database query (so just using the DefaultModelBinder) then what about database objects that have properties that are other db objects? These would never get assigned.

Saving an object after the user has edited it (1 or 2 properties are editable in the view) the ModelBinded object would be missing data, so saving it as it is would result in data in the database being overwritten with invalid values, or NOT-NULL constraints failing.

So, whats the best way to get an object in a controller action from the database bound with the form data posted back from the view?

Note im using NHibernate.

Comment: I'm in the exact same situation as you (also using NH). I have implemented a model binder to avoid code duplication. What's your conclusion about accessing the DB from the binder?

Comment: In the end I sided against database access in binders. My view models are now separate to my domain models. There are issues with binding directly to your domain models (nhibernate will flush the bound object at the end of the request with possibly invalid data, and unless you create a new session, re-getting the object you're after, you end up using the invalid binded object throughout the whole request).

Answer (score 4):

I get the model object from the database, then use UpdateModel (or TryUpdateModel) on the object to update values from the form parameters.

```
public ActionResult Update( int id )
{
     DataContext dc = new DataContext();
     MyModel model = dc.MyModels.Where( m => m.ID == id ).SingleOrDefault();

     string[] whitelist = new string[] { "Name", "Property1", "Property2" };

     if (!TryUpdateModel( model, whitelist )) {
        ... model error handling...
        return View("Edit");
     }

     ViewData.Model = model;

     return View("Show");
}
```

Comment: I've found that if I have a property on my model that is assigned to some value and that doesn't exist in the FormCollection, when doing TryUpdateModel the property is set to null even if I include/exclude properties. So basically TryUpdateModel is causing data loss, which isn't good.

Comment: It should only replace the properties that are in the whitelist if you've specified one.  I know that this works as I have some edit views that can only update some values not others.  You can look at the actual code for it at http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you don't have control over the construction of the model binder, so you can't inject any repository implementation.

You *can* reach out directly into a service locator to pull in your repository & fetch the item:

```
public class ProductBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
        ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        if(modelType != typeof(Product))
            return null;

        var form = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
        int id = Int32.Parse(form["Id"]);
        if(id == 0)
            return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);

        IProductRepository repository = ServiceLocator.Resolve<IProductRepository>();

        return repository.Fetch(id);                                    
    }       
}
```

You might even make this work for all of your entities if you can use a base class or interface that provides the Id of the class.

You'll have to set this up in Global.asax:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Product), new ProductBinder());
```

and then you can do this:

```
public ActionResult Save([Bind] Product product)
{
    ....

    _repository.Save(product);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was doing originally, as it makes sense to me to do it here. But having read in several places that the ModelBinder shouldn't query the database it's made me think twice.

Comment: It is a bit smelly, but if it makes you feel any better, [ARDataBind] from the Castle project does exactly this.

Comment: Hitting the database is the ModeBinder isn't a great idea.  Also, the binder executes BEFORE ActionFilters, so keep that in mind when accessing the database from binders

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point, you might access the database before a different action filter halts the request...

Answer (score 0):

Let me first state that I don't recommend to access database from ModelBinders, as from perspective of Separation Of Concern ModelBinders should only be responsible of interpretting client request, obviously database is not.
If you dont want to repeat your self (DRY), use repositories/services
However if u really want to do it like that, then

In global.asax.cs Register a custom MyModelBinderProvider to MVC

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new EntityModelBinderProvider 
{ 
     ConnectionString = "my connection string"
));
```

Cunstruct the custom ModelBinderProvider to contain database settings

```
public class EntityBinderProvider: IModelBinderProvider
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
    {
        if (Is known entity)
            return new EntityBinder(ConnectionString);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Follow further instructions from Ben Scheirman

Answer (score -1):

You don't actually have to hit the database.  Simply setting the Id of the objects will be enough to set the relationship up, but watch your cascades.  Make sure your cascde settings won't update the related object as it will clear the values.

Comment: That's really dangerous advice.  You should always select before update, because there are many areas where you might not be updating all the records in the database, which would end up overwriting with blank values.

Comment: Very true, was a stupid answer because I didn't read the question properly!